# Java RealmObject with Map field

Tags: java, realm

I created class that extends RealmObject.
and plan to add `Map` field like below, but I notice that Realm does not support `Map` yet.

```java
public class SmsPattern extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String address;
    @Required
    private String regex;
    @Required
    private Map<Integer, Integer> regexGroup;
}
```

So as an alternative, I will convert `Map` to `Json String` and use `Json String` instead of `Map` like this.

```java
public class SmsPattern extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String address;
    @Required
    private String regex;
    @Required
    private String regexGroup;
    @Ignore
    private Map<Integer, Integer> regexGroupMap;

    public Map<Integer, Integer> getRegexGroupMap() {
        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<Integer, Integer>>(){}.getType();
        return new Gson().fromJson(getRegexGroup(), type);
    }

    public void setRegexGroupMap(Map<Integer, Integer> regexGroupMap) {
        setRegexGroup(new Gson().toJson(regexGroupMap));
    }
}
```

Is this a normal solution?
Or any better idea?

Comment: Sorry to piggyback on your question. I am using realm 1.1.0, which has fixed several problems, but I am seeing a weird behavior where I put values in to an (at)Ignore Map field in my uniquely keyed RealmObject, but when I query the object the Map is empty. I think I understand why this is (because there is no persistence for (at)Ignore fields?), but then how is it useful to have any (at)Ignore fields in a RealmObject? Clearly I must be missing something obvious here...

Answer (score 1):

If you want a similar `RealmObject` which behaves like a map, you can declare one by your self like this:

```java
public class RegexGroup extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private int key;
    private int value
}

public class SmsPattern extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    private String id;
    @Required
    private String address;
    @Required
    private String regex;
    private RealmList<RegexGroup> regexGroup;
}
```

The benefits than your JSON string solution are

1. the `RegexGroup.key` is indexed, it will be very fast if you want to query one from them by key.
2. You don't have to load the whole "map" into the memory like what you have to (assume you are not using stream parser) when using JSON string.
3. There is a nature restriction guaranteed by the `@PrimaryKey` that your `RegexGroup.key` will be unique which makes it more like a map.

Comment: Many thanks for great answer @beeender. But how about the case that two different ```SmsPattern```'s ```RegexGroup``` has same key?

Comment: In that case maybe you can use `String` for the key, and follow this patter to generate the key: `SmsPattern.id_regexGroup.id` .